# leading zero / zero padding doesn't work properly

Tags: python

I am getting data from arduino via Serial (pySerial). It is then split in to 3 value by a delimiter(:). I am using slice ([0:5]) to remove 2 extra characters (I think it the new line).

So far so good. But then rjust or zfill or even format() simply does not work properly. If I use zfill(5) for example and the value output by arduino is 8.00 there is no change and I get 3 characters. If I use zfill(7) then it works and I get 7 total characters.

What is going on?

Arduino is outputting this every ~1 seconds: 22.00:36.00:58.00

```
import time
import serial

connected = False

port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
baud = 9600

ser = serial.Serial(port, baud)

# loop until arduino is ready
while not connected:
    serin = ser.read()
    connected = True

# read aruino output
while ser.readline():
    readings = ser.readline().split(':', 2)

    lum = readings[2][0:5].rjust(5, '0')
    #lum = readings[2][0:5].zfill(5) same result as with rjust

    print(lum)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I am using Arduino Uno connected to Raspberry Pi running Rasberian OS with IDLE as python editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readline()` contain newline. Strip newline.

```
readings = ser.readline().rstrip().split(':', 2)
```

---

```
>>> '0.00\n'.rjust(5, '0')
'0.00\n'
>>> '0.00\n'.rstrip().rjust(5, '0')
'00.00'
```